# Accidentally deleted mainWindow.xib

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mainwindow

In My iPad app, I accidentally deleted the MainWindow.Xib, any solution?

Thank you

Comment: search for it in the trash .. then add it to your project

Comment: When you've fixed this problem look at source control like Git to avoid these sticky situations

Answer (score 0):

copy-paste MainWindow.xib from another project of same template and set the class of that file to the name of your appdelegate class.
OR
Add new xib (uiapplication) and set its delegate to your app delegate

Comment: how to "set the class of that file to the name of your appdelegate class"? sorry i'm new in ios programming.

Answer (score 0):

you should recreate it then.

`File` -> `New` -> `File...` --- `iOS User Interface` -> `View` -> `Next` -> `iPad` -> `Next` -> set the name `MainViewController.xib` -> `Create` and *violá*...

you've done!

or...

use the *TimeMachine* to backup it or if you are using any version control system (i.e. git) you would just reset the deleting and you could get back the original `MainViewController.xib`.

Comment: I did it, but it's empty, how to link it with the delegate, view, i don't know, how to make it work like before?